# Regex find string by START-END pattern, with "options"

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I know the title may be confusing so here is what I needed to do:

```
Dim str = "blablabla blabla text-+-123.ipt blablabla sometext-+-456.iam bla someothertext-+-789.ipt blabla thistext+++000.doc"
```

my desired output is an Array/List of strings with:

123,456,789

currently I'm trying: `Regex.Matches (str, ".*\-\+\-(.*)[(.iam)(.ipt)]")` which comes close, but not close enough :)

the goal: Return all Substrings starting with "-+-" AND ending with (".iam" OR ".ipt") - w/o the pattern itself

SORRY: could be misleading, the output strings are not necessarily Numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the digits using

```
-\+-(.*?)\.(?:iam|ipt)
```

See the [regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%5c%2b-%28.*%3f%29%5c.%28%3f%3aiam%7cipt%29&i=blablabla+blabla+text-%2b-123.ipt+blablabla+sometext-%2b-456.iam+bla+someothertext-%2b-789.ipt+blabla+thistext%2b%2b%2b000.doc). You may also write it as `-\+-(.*?)\.i(?:am|pt)` to make it more efficient but less readable.

**Details**

- `-\+-` - a `-+-` literal substring
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:iam|ipt)` - either `iam` or `ipt` substring

[image]

VB.net code:

```
Dim matches As List(Of String) = Regex.Matches(text, "-\+-(.*?)\.i(?:am|pt)") _
                                         .Cast(Of Match)() _
                                         .Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value) _
                                         .ToList()
```

Comment: except (\d+) -> (.*) in my use case

Comment: @dba Well, that depends what actual data looks like. You posted a string with digits.

Comment: upvote for detailed explanation, wasn't aware of the (?:iam|ipt) syntax

Comment: and edited my question regarding this... anyway, your solution works I just added the alternative for free string if someone (unexperienced in Regex - like me) stumbles on this

Answer (score 0):

```
const string pattern = @"[-][+][-](\d+)[.][ipt|iam]";
```

not numbers

```
const string pattern = @"[-][+][-]([^.]+)[.][ipt|iam]";
```

to extract matches

```
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var content = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

OR

```
var results = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the participation, found a solution using named capture Groups:

`Dim reg As New Regex("-\+-(?<Number>.*?)[(\.iam)(\.ipt)]")
Dim m = reg.Matches(str).Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(x) x.Groups("Number")).ToArray()`

Comment: The `[(.iam)(.ipt)]` is wrong, you might as well put `\.` here instead.

Comment: `[(.iam)(.ipt)]` matches a single char: `(`, `.`, `i`, `a`, `m`, `)`, `p`, `t` and is equal to `[(.iam)pt]`. It is a positive character class, it does not match a sequence of chars, but any chars inside it.

Comment: okay, you're rigth, it gave the correct results so I didn't care :)